# Time Optional using the date_popup type

Tags: forms

Is there a way to have date/time fields with the date_popup type, but have the time field be something optional for the user to fill in?

I have the UI with both a Date and Time field with the following code:

```
$form['mygsb_settings']["publish_on_start_date"] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => "Publish Start Date",
);
```

But when a user doesn't enter the start time, I get back the following validation error from drupal.

The value input for field Publish Start Date is invalid:
The value 2012-03-14 does not match the expected format.

Is there any way to avoid this validation error? Basically, I want to make the time field optional.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

I needed to allow users to give either a datetime or just a date, so I needed to override the default date_popup behaviour. NOTE: I am not using the date fields provided with the date uri, just the date_popup form element.

You can override the default date_popup validation. The data_popup module applies the validation function during the `date_popup_element_process` function.

I used a `hook_element_info_alter` function to append a custom process function AFTER the `date_popup_element_process` and applied my own validation function. Like so:

```
function hook_element_info_alter(&$type) {
    $type['date_popup']['#process'][] = 'my_popup_date_process';
}

function my_popup_date_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
    $element['#element_validate'] = array('my_popup_date_validate');
    return $element;
}

function my_popup_date_validate() {
    if (isset($form_state['values'][$element['#field_name']])) {
        if (trim($form_state['values'][$element['#field_name']][$element['#language']][0]['time']) == '') {
            list($date_format, $time_format) = explode(" ", $element['#date_format']);
            $element['#date_format'] = trim($date_format);
        }
    }
    date_popup_validate($element, $form_state);
}
```

Removed unneeded code for brevity. Updated validation funciton with an example showing how this could be achieved. This example assumes that there is a space between the data and time formats (ie "d/m/Y H:i:s") and that the date format is first.

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
'#required' => FALSE,
```

could help .. see [forms API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)